# Django django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.static removed in 3.0: How could I replace the functionality?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, static-files, django-3.0

I have the following code block where a corresponding `.css` file's path is returned. 
It is part of a `Theme-Class` that allows the user to change the website theme (dark and light) 
from a button in the profile view.

```
def link(self) -> str:
        """
        Returns the link where the CSS file for this theme is located
        """
        return static('app_shared/colors_%s.css' % self.name())
```

The same problem when it occurs in an HTML-Template can be solved by changing `{% load staticfiles %}` to `{% load static %}`. Obviously for source code I will need another alternative.

Answer (score 15):

django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags was deprecated in Django's [version 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.1/#id2). And now it has been completely removed from [version 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/).

Simply, replace

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
```

with

```
from django.templatetags.static import static
```

Hope this will help...

Answer (score 6):

You're misunderstanding what's being removed. `django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.static()` is deprecated in favor of `django.templatetags.static.static()`. If you use the latter, everything will work as you expect it.

See the [Django 2.1 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.1/#id2), when this was deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to get my project static files working on Django 3.0:

Previously in settings.py I had the following:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'builtins': [
                'django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles', 
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

Because of the change you mentioned, now I have:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'builtins': [
                'django.templatetags.static',  # <------------ New way
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

and it works again.

I kind of wish this was just a standard part of Django as this has been pretty much necessary in all of my projects, but alas, this works.